# Why Jenkins "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", but "Finished: FAILURE"?

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration

I set up Jenkins job with php template http://jenkins-php.org/ and also using https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/money for test.
After building is finished, I got a message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 58 seconds
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log with parser PHP Runtime
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd.xml
[PMD] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace
[PMD] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace/build/logs/pmd.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
[DRY] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace
[DRY] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/builds/4/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[CRAP4J] Collecting Crap4J analysis files...
[CRAP4J] Searching for report files within build/logs/crap4j.xml
[CRAP4J] Using the new FileSetBuilder
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace/build/api to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/builds/4/htmlreports/API_Documentation
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 188 classes in 1 packages
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins log:

```
мар 17, 2016 11:24:46 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: New job #4 main build action completed: SUCCESS
мар 17, 2016 11:24:47 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.service.XUnitService infoSystemLogger
INFO: [xUnit] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.
[warn] [XHTML Sink] Modified invalid anchor name: 'SebastianBergmann\Money' to 'SebastianBergmannMoney'
```

What I do wrong?

UPDATE: The problem has been that I did not have "php5-xdebug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues in the message.

Clover results were not found:

```
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/New job/builds/4/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
```

Crap results were not found:

```
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure
```

I cannot tell you what exactly you are doing wrong, but checking your configuration could help you identify the cause.

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been that I did not have "php5-xdebug"

Answer (score 1):

Your job is marked as failure because of this build step:

```
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure
```

You have to investigate why this Crap report is missing.

Answer (score 0):

move your phpdox.xml to the project root

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?